# How to make the enabling of a given layer, in a keras model, trainable?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have the following siamese model:

[image]

I would like to make the enabling/disabling of layers `a-L1` and `b-L1` trainable. ie: `a-L1` and/or `b-L1` should be transparent (not used or disabled) for the current input if necessary. So, the model after training, will learn when it should enable/disable one or both of the layers `a-L1` and `b-L1`.
I managed to train this model with 4 cases, so I got 4 different models accordingly:

- model-1: without a-L1 and b-L1
- model-2: without a-L1
- model-3: without b-L1
- model-4: with both a-L1 and b-L1

the performances of these models complement each other and I would like to combine them. Do you have some suggestions, please?

Comment: do you want to merge all four models?

Comment: yes, it would be something like a merge function, but with keeping the same architecture, the ideal will be a function with some trainable parameters enabling to disable or enable the purple layers `a-L1` and `b-L1`.

Comment: Use additional weight parameters which can be trained for each layer's output. Then the total output will be weighted sum of the  previous layers.

Comment: Could you give more details in an answer, please? or give an example or some keras code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider you have trained four models and them let's call them m1, m2, m3 and m4

first define the input layer which is common for all of them.

```
inputs = Input(shape=your_inputs_shape)

model_1_output = m1(inputs)
model_2_output = m2(inputs)
model_3_output = m3(inputs)
model_4_output = m4(inputs)
merged_layer = Concatenate(axis=your_concatanation_axis)([model_1_output, model_2_output, model_3_output,model_4_output)
new_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=merged_layer)
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

### EDIT:

To answer your question on comment, It is possible to combine only the layers before L2. But you have to decide which model's layers starting from L2, you are going to use(Since you are not combining layers starting from L2). Let's assume you want to use m1 model's layers after L2. In addition I want to add the weighting mechanism I've specified above in comments of the answer.

#### First let's define new models with common new inputs

```
new_inputs = Input(shape=(inputs_shape))
new_m1 = keras.models.Model(inputs = new_inputs, outputs = m1(new_inputs))
new_m2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = new_inputs, outputs = m2(new_inputs))
new_m3 = keras.models.Model(inputs = new_inputs, outputs = m3(new_inputs))
new_m4 = keras.models.Model(inputs = new_inputs, outputs = m4(new_inputs))
```

#### Now get the L2 layer for all models

```
model1_l2 = new_m1.layers[1].get_layer("L2").output
model2_l2 = new_m2.layers[1].get_layer("L2").output
model3_l2 = new_m3.layers[1].get_layer("L2").output
model4_l2 = new_m4.layers[1].get_layer("L2").output
```

#### weighted merge

```
merged = Concatenate(axis=your_concatanation_axis)([model1_l2, model2_l2, model3_l2,model4_l2])
merged_layer_shape = merged.get_shape().as_list()

# specify number of channels you want the output to have after merging

desired_output_channels = 32

new_trainable_weights =  keras.backend.random_normal_variable(shape=(merged_layer_shape[-1], desired_output_channels),mean=0,scale=1)
weighted_output = keras.backend.dot(merged,new_trainable_weights)
```

#### now connect the layer of model1(m1) next to L2 with this new weighted_output

```
# I'm using some protected properties of layer. But it is not recommended way to do it.
# get the index of l2 layer in new_m1
for i in range(len(new_m1.layers[1].layers)):
    if new_m1.layers[1].layers[i].name=="L2":
        index = i
x = weighted_output
for i in range(index+1, len(new_m1.layers[1].layers)):
    x = new_m1.layers[1].layers[i](x)

new_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=new_inputs, outputs=x)
```

Comment: You mean that I will combine the entire models after being trained separately, this is a good idea. It's another model really interesting. Ann, what do you propose to combine only the layers before `L2`? such that I keep the architecture unchanged (siamese one)?

Comment: Thanks @Mitiku it really helped me.